# How do you fix "cannot install Google Drive in this location" on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

How do you fix "cannot install Google Drive in this location" on macOS High Sierra?

I've removed Google Sync and Backup.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to [System requirements and browsers](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), Google Drive needs at least macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina), so High Sierra (10.13) is just too old for this.

This is also reflected in the system requirements defined in the installation package itself.

[image: Screenshot of PackageInfo file of GoogleDrive.pkg, showing minimumSystemVersion set to 10.15.7]

Comment: Which means that if the MBP is Mid-2012 or later, it can be upgraded to Catalina; but if earlier than that, it can't.

Comment: According to this https://photos.google.com/apps it needs macOS 10.9 +

Comment: @Snowcrash Looks like that page (which is primarily about Google Photos) is outdated.

Answer (score -1):

i solved installing an old version 63.0.5
the message "google drive does not support your version of MacOS" still apears but the app is fully usable

https://google-drive.uptodown.com/mac/descargar/82266878

Comment: The usual risks involved in using software from un unknown source should be considered here.